# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges to any arbitrary real number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been reading about Riemann series theorem and I think I understand the proof and the idea. But still, I have the feeling that something is wrong with it. For instance, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=1$ doesn't this mean $0=1$?

Comment: When changing $\sigma$ a permutation of the integers then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\sigma(n)}}{\sigma(n)}$ can diverge or converge to any real number. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is with the trivial permutation $\sigma(n) = n$, it converges and its value is well-defined, unique

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n/n$ has exactly one value (i.e. the limit of its partial sums).  The sums of its permutations (i.e. the rearranged sums discussed in the theorem) are (counterintuitively) **not** necessarily equal to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n/n$.

Comment: Can you explain further how a permutation in the terms of the series makes a difference in its sum?

Comment: "if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=1$ doesn't this mean $0=1$?" Yes it implies $0=1.$ Fortunately neither of the "ifs" is correct.

Comment: Downvoters: this is a genuine confusion many people have, and it's clearly expressed. That makes it a useful question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An explanation, rather than a complete proof, of how the reordered series can converge to any predefined limit.

Consider a conditionally convergent series such as the one in your question. The series of positive terms $\sum p_n$ diverges, as does the series of negative terms $\sum q_m$.

Choose $a$ to be whatever limit you want the **reordered** series—not the original series—to converge to. For the sake of argument let's use $a>0$.

Since $\sum p_n$ diverges, you can take just enough terms from the start of the sequence $(p_n)$ to add up to $>a$. Next, since $\sum q_m$ also diverges, you can follow these with just enough terms from $(q_n)$ to get the sum back below $a$. Switch back to taking positive terms to get above $a$ again.

Continue like this, alternating between groups of positive and negative terms. Each time, the amount by which you overshoot $a$ is no more than the size of the last term used.

Now, since the original series is convergent, the sequences $(p_n)$ and $(q_m)$ both converge to $0$. So the size of the "overshoot" also converges to $0$. In other words, the reordered series we're constructing converges to $a$.

The divergerce of $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ guarantees you never get stuck one side of $a$, and convergence of $(p_n)$ and $(q_m)$ to $0$ guarantees that the reordered series converges.

The crucial point is that the reordered series *isn't the same series*, and its limit is the **limit of the process** of adding more terms—not the sum of "all the positive terms and all the negative terms", which is $\infty-\infty$ and hence undefined.

---

**Edit:** I think a big source of confusion here is the notation $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ which looks as though it should mean "Collect all the infinitely many terms $a_n$ together and find their sum". But **it's defined not to mean that** because the sum doesn't always exist. Instead it's defined as the limit of a sequence of finite sums containing more and more terms. Changing the order of the terms changes the sequence of sums, which can sometimes change the limit.

Comment: "it's defined as the limit of a sequence of finite sums containing more and more terms." Aaaaaaah. Something just clicked! I understand now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shay Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann series theorem has nothing to do with the sum of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n$ which is equal to $-\log2$ (but it's *not* equal to $0$ or to $1$).

If you apply the theorem to this series, what it tells you is that, for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, there is some bijection $b\colon\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb N$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{b(n)}}{b(n)}=\alpha$.

Comment: Can you explain how a permutation of the series' terms changes its sum? It is really counterintuitive for me.

Comment: Take a look at [the proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Proof).

Comment: Yes, I understand the proof, and I accept it's true. Even then, I still don't understand why $\sum a_{\sigma(n)}$ would be different from $\sum a_n$. They all have the same terms, it's just a permutation. Infinity is weird.

Comment: @Shay Yes, the problem is the infinity, and, probably, the definition of the series.   To avoid the problem it would be sufficient to require a canonical order of the terms (e.g. $\forall m>n: |a_m|\le|a_n|$). Actually most series are in this form and I know no case where some other order has a practical importance.

Comment: @shay It's because the literal "sum" would be $\infty-\infty$ so is undefined. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is shorthand for "take the limit of the sequence of finite sums", not "add up all the terms". Changing the order of the terms changes the sequence of partial sums.